# Kendo UI for loop data binding

Tags: listview, data-binding, kendo-ui, observable

I have such  a code in my project:

```
<script id="menuTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
   # for(var i=0; i < menus.menu.length; i++){ # 
   <li id="menu-#= i#" data-bind="events: {click: menuClick}" class="menu-item">
       <div>#= menus.menu[i].name #</div>
   </li>  
   # } #
</script>
<div data-role="view" id="menuPage" data-model="menuViewModel">
    <ul id="menuListView" data-role="listview" data-template="menuTemplate" data-bind="source: dataSource"></ul>
</div>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
  var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: { 
        read: { 
            url: "data/test.json", 
            dataType: "json", 
        },
    },
    schema: {
        data: function(data) {   
            return data;
        }
    },
});

var menuViewModel = kendo.observable({
    dataSource: dataSource,
    menuClick: function(e) {
        alert(e);
    }
});
kendo.bind($(document.body), menuViewModel); 
});
</script>
```

So I have listview Items and I want bind clicks on them. 
The problem is that click binds only to the first element of the listview, so alert fires only when I click to the element with the "menu-0" id.
What I write wrong and how bind the handler properly so menuClick function will be handler for all listview items?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you post an example of what you're getting back from data/test.json?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrapping list items into div solves the issue:

```
<script id="menuTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
<div>
   # for(var i=0; i < menus.menu.length; i++){ # 
   <li id="menu-#= i#" data-bind="events: {click: menuClick}" class="menu-item">
       <div>#= menus.menu[i].name #</div>
   </li>  
   # } #
</div>
</script>
```